# Replace space(x0020) from string in Regex C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am not good at Regex, and I think I am close.  I have some data coming back from a list and populating a dropdown. I am getting *x0200* representation instead of a space.  I have tried Regex, but I think I am wrong here.

```
foreach (string field in myViewFields)
{
    SPField myField = list.Fields.GetField(field);
    SPFieldType fieldType = myField.Type;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fieldType);

    if (fieldType == SPFieldType.Text || fieldType == SPFieldType.Note)
    {
        var fieldSpace = field;
        fieldSpace = Regex.Replace(fieldSpace, @"[\x20\x27\x2C\.]", "");
        ddlListColumns.Items.Add(fieldSpace);
    }

}
```

Please let me know what it is I am doing wrong here.  I just want to replace of these damn hex spaces.

Comment: you want to replace a space from a string .. ?

Comment: I want to replace the _x0200_ from the string and replace it with a " " space

Comment: Any reason `string.Replace` will not do?

Comment: By the way - `""` is an empty string, not a space - that would be `" "`.

Comment: Also, not sure why you think that would do anything, after all in C#, `'\x0020' == ' '`.

Comment: Please show where you get `x0020` - in the display? The debugger?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an html parser and only want to focus on space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String.Replace :

```
@"my\x0020bar".Replace(@"\x0020", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can just use `string.Replace()`

```
var fieldSpace = field;
string replaced = fieldspace.Replace(@"\x0020"," ");
ddlListColumns.Items.Add(replaced);
```

Comment: Worked Great!  Guess I need to brush up a little on my C# thanks :)